# Telnet to locahost refused, but via IP works?

Tags: linux, jboss, ip, localhost, telnet

I have a weird problem, to be specific it's about Jboss's JNDI and on linux.
If I'm on the server via ssh (Putty) and run the following:

telnet localhost 1099

It tells me connection refused, but... If I run:

telnet x 1099

where x is the ip address of the server, it connects, all this on the actual server.

How can this be? shouldn't work via localhost? I also tried 127.0.0.1 with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like the program is binding to a specific IP address or network interface.  Run `netstat -tnlp | grep :1099` and you will probably see that it is listening on a non-loopback interface.

If you can instruct the application to listen on `0.0.0.0` (the IPv4 wildcard address) then it will be accessible from any network interface on the machine.

Comment: So JBoss's binding address should be 0.0.0.0 ? Or else how can the JNDI service bind to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: That would be one solution, yes.

Comment: I've tried it, Jboss is binding to 0.0.0.0 and the problem persists, this is the output from "netstat -tnlp | grep :1099" = "tcp        0      0 172.20.41.135:1099          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      30306/java"

Comment: It's still binding to 172.20.41.135, according to that output.

Comment: I see, I'll have a look at that, accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your JBoss instance was started with the option **--host=x**  (or **-b x**)  where *x* is the IP address (not 127.0.0.1, not 0.0.0.0 and not localhost). This means JNDI will only listen on *x*.

You can determine if this is the case by inspecting the system properties in JMXConsole. Find the MBean **jboss:name=SystemProperties,type=Service**. Find the operation called **showAll** and invoke it. The system properties will be displayed. Look for the value of **jboss.bind.address** and you may find that it says *x* instead of 0.0.0.0 which it sounds is what you really want.

Having said that, you may have a specific override for the binding address on the naming (jndi) service. The **--host=**  or **-b** options set the property **jboss.bind.address** which becomes the *default* binding address for nearly all the network services, but it is possible to configure individual services to specific bind addresses that are different from **jboss.bind.address**. Take a look at the **jboss:service=Naming** MBean in JMXConsole , and look for the **BindAddress** attribute. That address indicates the interfaces where you can connect to. (If it's 0.0.0.0, then it's *all* your interfaces.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The JBoss binding address is 0.0.0.0, but in the JMX console, the jndi binding address is x ? could that be the issue?

Comment: Yup. That's the issue. Check your (jboss-home)/server/(server-name)/conf/jboss-service.xml. look for the jboss:service=Naming. Either comment out the BindAddress attribute, or set it to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the loopback interface is up?

```
# ifconfig lo
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          ...
```

If you don't see `UP LOOPBACK RUNNING`, but instead only `LOOPBACK`, start the loopback interface with `ifconfig lo up` and try again.

Comment: I'll try this when I'm back at work. How can I make sure the loopback starts up on a server restart though?

Comment: It depends on your distribution. On Debian, for example, you'd need to adapt /etc/network/interfaces. On Red Hat, I think you'd have to look at /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts.

Comment: I see UP LOOPBACK RUNNING, any other suggestions?